# Focus on iOS Checkboxes jquery plugin elements

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm using this plugin in a project: [iOS Checkboxes](http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/)

Problem is, I'm not sure it provides a class or some focus styles out of the box (when navigating with the keyboard) in order to give a visual clue to the user.

Even if you try to tab-navigate in the plugin's page, those iphone checkbox elements won't get any distinctive look when being focused (I assume they are focused because if you hit spacebar, their functionality is triggered)

Does anyone have any experience with this plugin or has any idea how that focus look can be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to add a focus/blur handler on the styled checkboxes to set some styles on the current focused element.

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(':checkbox').iphoneStyle();

     $(':checkbox').on('focus', function () {
         $(this).closest('.iPhoneCheckContainer').addClass('focusContainer');
     })
     $(':checkbox').on('blur', function () {
         $(this).closest('.iPhoneCheckContainer').removeClass('focusContainer');
     })
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/g24Qp/